# GDAL polygonize only certain raster values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, polygonize

I want to polygonize a raster file with GDAL. I only want to rasterize cells with a value of 0. Is it possible to specify that within the [polygonize function](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) or do I have to modify my raster before hand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible directly in the function. You can either a) reclassify the raster first (probably fastest and easiest), or 2) convert to vector then delete all non-zero polygons, or 3) create a mask, and pass that to gdal_polygonize using -mask ([see manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html).)

Comment: Thank for suggestions. I tested the first and third methods, and the third one works for me. The reason why the first one did not work was that even if I reclassified the raster (1 for the part, which I want to polygonize, nodata for the part, which I want to delete), the GDAL polygonize function still converted the whole raster into polygons. So, just classify raster into 1 and 0 for the mask, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Just to mention that using the -mask parameter makes the process faster for me. Just tested with both options